# Why is my Ajax cannot save data into database? Laravel with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to save data using ajax. The ajax is inside my javascript file and passed to my controller and route. However the issue is it cannot save the data into my database.

Here is my jquery.hotspot.js file that include ajax:

```js
(function ($) {

    var defaults = {

        // Object to hold the hotspot data points
        data: [],

        // Element tag upon which hotspot is (to be) build
        tag: 'img',

        // Specify mode in which the plugin is to be used
        // `admin`: Allows to create hotspot from UI
        // `display`: Display hotspots from `data` object
        mode: 'display',

        // HTML5 LocalStorage variable where hotspot data points are (will be) stored
        LS_Variable: '__HotspotPlugin_LocalStorage',

        // CSS class for hotspot data points
        hotspotClass: 'HotspotPlugin_Hotspot',

        // CSS class which is added when hotspot is to hidden
        hiddenClass: 'HotspotPlugin_Hotspot_Hidden',

        // Event on which the hotspot data point will show up
        // allowed values: `click`, `hover`, `none`
        interactivity: 'hover',

        // Action button CSS classes used in `admin` mode
        save_Button_Class: 'HotspotPlugin_Save',
        remove_Button_Class: 'HotspotPlugin_Remove',
        send_Button_Class: 'HotspotPlugin_Send',

        // CSS class for hotspot data points that are yet to be saved
        unsavedHotspotClass: 'HotspotPlugin_Hotspot_Unsaved',

        // CSS class for overlay used in `admin` mode
        hotspotOverlayClass: 'HotspotPlugin_Overlay',

        // Enable `ajax` to read data directly from server
        ajax: false,
        ajaxOptions: { url: '' },

        listenOnResize: true,

        // Hotspot schema
        schema: [
            {
                'property': 'Title',
                'default': ''
            },
            {
                'property': 'Message',
                'default': ''
            }
        ]
    };

    // Constructor
    function Hotspot(element, options) {

        var widget = this;

        // Overwriting defaults with options
        this.config = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

        this.element = element;

        // `tagElement`: element for which hotspots are being done
        this.tagElement = element.find(this.config.tag);

        // Register event listeners
        $.each(this.config, function (index, fn) {
            if (typeof fn === 'function') {
                widget.element.on(index + '.hotspot', function (event, err, data) {
                    fn(err, data);
                });
            }
        });

        if (this.config.mode != 'admin' && this.config.listenOnResize) {
            $(window).on('resize', function () {
                $(element).find('.' + widget.config.hotspotClass).remove();
                widget.init();
            });
        }

        if (this.config.tag !== 'img') {
            widget.init();
            return;
        }

        if (this.tagElement.prop('complete')) {
            widget.init();
        } else {
            this.tagElement.one('load', function (event) {
                widget.init();
            });
        }
    }

    Hotspot.prototype.init = function () {
        this.parseData();

        // Fetch data for `display` mode with `ajax` enabled
        if (this.config.mode != 'admin' && this.config.ajax) {
            this.fetchData();
        }

        // Nothing else to do here for `display` mode
        if (this.config.mode != 'admin') {
            return;
        }

        this.setupWorkspace();
    };

    Hotspot.prototype.createId = function () {
        var id = "";
        var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            id += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
        }

        return id;
    };

    Hotspot.prototype.setupWorkspace = function () {
        var widget = this;

        // `data` array: to contain hotspot objects
        var data = [];

        var tHeight = $(widget.tagElement[0]).height(),
            tWidth = $(widget.tagElement[0]).width(),
            tOffset = widget.tagElement.offset(),
            pHeight = $(widget.element[0]).height(),
            pWidth = $(widget.element[0]).width(),
            pOffset = widget.element.offset();

        // Create overlay for the tagElement
        $('<span/>', {
            html: '<p>Click this Panel to Store Messages</p>'
        }).css({
            'height': (tHeight / pHeight) * 100 + '%',
            'width': (tWidth / pWidth) * 100 + '%',
            'left': (tOffset.left - pOffset.left) + 'px',
            'top': (tOffset.top - pOffset.top) + 'px'
        }).addClass(widget.config.hotspotOverlayClass).appendTo(widget.element);

        // Handle click on overlay mask
        this.element.delegate('span', 'click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            // Get coordinates
            var offset = $(this).offset(),
                relativeX = (event.pageX - offset.left),
                relativeY = (event.pageY - offset.top);

            var height = $(widget.tagElement[0]).height(),
                width = $(widget.tagElement[0]).width();

            var hotspot = { x: relativeX / width * 100, y: relativeY / height * 100 };

            var schema = widget.config.schema;

            for (var i = 0; i < schema.length; i++) {
                var val = schema[i];
                var fill = prompt('Please enter ' + val.property, val.default);
                if (fill === null) {
                    return;
                }
                hotspot[val.property] = fill;
            }

            data.push(hotspot);

            // Temporarily display the spot
            widget.displaySpot(hotspot, true);
        });

        // Register admin controls
        var button_id = this.createId();

        $('<button/>', {
            text: "Save data"
        }).prop('id', ('save' + button_id)).addClass(this.config.save_Button_Class).appendTo(this.element);

        $('<button/>', {
            text: "Remove data"
        }).prop('id', ('remove' + button_id)).addClass(this.config.remove_Button_Class).appendTo(this.element);

        $(this.element).delegate('button#' + ('save' + button_id), 'click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            widget.saveData(data);
            data = [];
        });

        $(this.element).delegate('button#' + ('remove' + button_id), 'click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            widget.removeData();
        });

        if (this.config.ajax) {
            $('<button/>', {
                text: "Send to server"
            }).prop('id', ('send' + button_id)).addClass(this.config.send_Button_Class).appendTo(this.element);

            $(this.element).delegate('button#' + ('send' + button_id), 'click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                widget.sendData();
            });
        }
    };

    Hotspot.prototype.fetchData = function () {
        var widget = this;

        // Fetch data from a server
        var options = {
            data: {
                HotspotPlugin_mode: "Retrieve"
            }
        };

        $.ajax($.extend({}, this.config.ajaxOptions, options))
            .done(function (data) {
                // Storing in localStorage
                localStorage.setItem(widget.config.LS_Variable, data);
                widget.parseData();                   
            })
            .fail($.noop);                
    };

    Hotspot.prototype.parseData = function () {
        var widget = this;

        var data = this.config.data,
            data_from_storage = localStorage.getItem(this.config.LS_Variable);

        if (data_from_storage && (this.config.mode === 'admin' || !this.config.data.length)) {
            data = JSON.parse(data_from_storage);
        }

        $.each(data, function (index, hotspot) {
        widget.displaySpot(hotspot);

        });
        
    };

    Hotspot.prototype.displaySpot = function (hotspot, unsaved) {
        var widget = this;

        var spot_html = $('<div/>');

        $.each(hotspot, function (index, val) {
            if (typeof val === "string") {
                $('<div/>', {
                    html: val
                }).addClass('Hotspot_' + index).appendTo(spot_html);
            }
        
        });

        var height = $(this.tagElement[0]).height(),
            width = $(this.tagElement[0]).width(),
            offset = this.tagElement.offset(),
            parent_offset = this.element.offset();

        var spot = $('<div/>', {
            html: spot_html
        }).css({
            'top': (hotspot.y * height / 100) + (offset.top - parent_offset.top) + 'px',
            'left': (hotspot.x * width / 100) + (offset.left - parent_offset.left) + 'px'
        }).addClass(this.config.hotspotClass).appendTo(this.element);

        if (unsaved) {
            spot.addClass(this.config.unsavedHotspotClass);
        }

        if (this.config.interactivity === 'hover') {
            return;
        }

        // Overwrite CSS rule for `none` & `click` interactivity
        spot_html.css('display', 'block');

        // Initially keep hidden
        if (this.config.interactivity !== 'none') {
            spot_html.addClass(this.config.hiddenClass);
        }

        if (this.config.interactivity === 'click') {
            spot.on('click', function (event) {
                spot_html.toggleClass(widget.config.hiddenClass);
            });
        } else {
            spot_html.removeClass(this.config.hiddenClass);
        }
    };

    Hotspot.prototype.saveData = function (data) {
        if (!data.length) {
            return;
        }

        // Get previous data
        var raw_data = localStorage.getItem(this.config.LS_Variable);

        var hotspots = [];

        if (raw_data) {
            hotspots = JSON.parse(raw_data);
        }

        // Append to previous data
        $.each(data, function (index, node) {
            hotspots.push(node);
        });

        this.data=data;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/store",
            dataType:'json',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data:{
                Title:$('#Title').val(),
                Message: $('#Message').val(),
                x:$('#relativeX').val(),
                y: $('#relativeY').val(),
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data,d);
            },
            error: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            },
           
        });
        

        localStorage.setItem(this.config.LS_Variable, JSON.stringify(hotspots));

        this.element.trigger('afterSave.hotspot', [null, hotspots]);
    };

    Hotspot.prototype.removeData = function () {
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.config.LS_Variable) === null) {
            return;
        }
        if (!confirm("Are you sure you wanna do everything?")) {
            return;
        }
        localStorage.removeItem(this.config.LS_Variable);
        this.element.trigger('afterRemove.hotspot', [null, 'Removed']);
    };

    Hotspot.prototype.sendData = function () {
        if (localStorage.getItem(this.config.LS_Variable) === null || !this.config.ajax) {
            return;
        }

        var widget = this;

        var options = {
            data: {
                HotspotPlugin_data: localStorage.getItem(this.config.LS_Variable),
                HotspotPlugin_mode: "Store"
            }
        };

        $.ajax($.extend({}, this.config.ajaxOptions, options))
            .done(function () {
                widget.element.trigger('afterSend.hotspot', [null, 'Sent']);
            })
            .fail(function (err) {
                widget.element.trigger('afterSend.hotspot', [err]);
            });
    };

    $.fn.hotspot = function (options) {
        new Hotspot(this, options);
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('hotspots','ImageController@getPin');
Route::post('store','ImageController@storePin')->name('store.storePin');
```

Here is my ImageController.php:

```
 public function getPin()
{
    $pin= Pin::select('Title','Message','x','y');
    return hotspot::of($pin)->make(true);
}
public function storePin(Request $request)
{

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'Title' => 'required',
        'Message'  => 'required',
        'x'=>'required',
        'y'=>'required',
     ]);

         if ($request->get('save','button_id') == "insert")
         {
             $pin = new Pin();
             $pin->Title=$request->Title;
             $pin->Message= $request->Message;
             $pin->x = $request->relativeX;
             $pin->y =$request->relativeY;

             $pin->save();
             //return Request::json($request);               
         }
}
```

Here is my hotspot.blade.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Picomment Hotspot</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset ('css/bootsrap.min.css') }}">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset ('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset ('css/jquery.hotspot.css') }}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset ('css/style.css') }}">
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
 
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 40px;">
  <div id="theElement-a">
   <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$files) }}" alt="" title=""> 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset ('js/jquery.hotspot.js') }}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theElement-a").hotspot({
   mode: "admin",
   // uncomment
   /*ajax: true,
   ajaxOptions: {
    'url': 'links.to.server'
   },*/
   interactivity: "click",
   LS_Variable: "HotspotPlugin-a",

   afterSave: function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
     console.log('Error occurred', err);
     return;
    }
    
    alert('Saved');
    // `data` in json format can be stored
    //  & passed in `display` mode for the image
   
                localStorage.clear();
    console.log(data);
   },
   afterRemove: function(err, message) {
    if (err) {
     console.log('Error occurred', err);
     return;
    }
    alert(message);
    window.location.reload();
   },
   afterSend: function(err, message) {
    if (err) {
     console.log('Error occurred', err);
     return;
    }
    alert(message);
   }
  });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: before  this i get error 500 internal server error but already fix and no error but stil cannot save into database

Comment: in the hotspot.blade.php.....sorry im still new in the coding world

Comment: yes should be like that...so when user click the save button it will store in localstorage ut i want to save into my database that is why i use ajax

Comment: sorry may i know how to know if it hitting my controller??

Comment: can you do `dd('here')` before `$validation = Validator::make($request->all(), [` this line in your `ImageController@storePin` method? and let know the result?

Comment: i only get response text like this <script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-r